# Mirror site for the NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions (DLMF)

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, special-functions, online-resources

For research I use the NIST Digital Library of Mathematical Functions (https://dlmf.nist.gov/) quite often for looking up basic facts about special functions. At the moment, however, this gives

> Sorry, but due to fact that the federal government is currently shut down, the website dlmf.nist.gov will be unavailable until further notice.

Does anyone know if the DLMF has a mirror site?

Comment: Back in 2013, I commented in a referee's report of my similar experience, and suggested (somewhat bizarrely IMO) that the author(s) also cite the (non-digital) hard-copy "NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions" from CUP. But web.archive.org is often your friend. E.g. http://web.archive.org/web/20180224092404/https://dlmf.nist.gov

Comment: this must be one of the most unexpected consequences of The Shutdown ;)

Comment: Looks like you'll need to locate a physical copy closest to you: https://www.worldcat.org/title/nist-handbook-of-mathematical-functions/oclc/837238676&referer=brief_results

Comment: In the meantime, a useful alternative is the database on special functions maintained by Wolfram: http://functions.wolfram.com/

Comment: To put posterity's mind at ease, the DLMF site is currently back up.